# Table to fit and not scale down

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I could take any bbcode, parse it and put it in the forum ad area without much modification. Since I changed the ad area a few months ago, the ad area now tends to totally mess up such ads. It seems to insert line breaks between most elements.

So, I want to do something like this without any javascript, using classes and not IDS and valid XHTML 1.0 Transitional

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SW08.png)

But it should look wrong scale down

[wrong scale down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3yhV.png)

Test website with scale down

> scaledown wsrong.esy.es/index.html (REMOVE SPACE)

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of a class defined in your test page which applies `min-width:100%` and `display:inline-block;` to your table cells:

```
.APNFQEmuvdnRbBnOdYJEyg table,.APNFQEmuvdnRbBnOdYJEyg tbody,.APNFQEmuvdnRbBnOdYJEyg tr,.APNFQEmuvdnRbBnOdYJEyg td {
  display:inline-block; max-width:100%; min-width:100%; overflow:hidden
}
```

So, you should prevent that class to be applied to your table or edit that style class (at line 30)

or somehow override it by adding a new class like as below:

```
.noMinWidth tr, .noMinWidth td { min-width:0; }
```

and apply it to your parent row containing your code

```
<tr class="APNFQEmuvdnRbBnOdYJEyg noMinWidth"> ...
```

Note: i see you use `<tr class="APNFQEmuvdnRbBnOdYJEyg" style="min-width: initial;">` for the parent row containing your code but the APNFQEmuvdnRbBnOdYJEyg class will also be applied to all `td` cells inside your tr which overrides that `min-width: initial;` style you set.